# Transaction with only one command

Tags: sql, postgresql

If in a transaction only one command is issued until `COMMIT`, is it equivalent to omitting the transaction altogether? (specifically in Postgres)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, I quote from their documentation:

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed
>   within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each
>   individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT
>   wrapped around it. A group of statements surrounded by BEGIN and
>   COMMIT is sometimes called a transaction block.

Found here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-transactions.html

Answer (score 1):

Every command in postgresql is in itself a transaction:

[*PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-transactions.html)